# GridView not populating from LINQ statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, web-applications

I have a GridView which is not bound to any DataSource. In my page load event I am writing this code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string getEntity = Request.QueryString["EntityID"];
        int getIntEntity = Int16.Parse(getEntity);

        OISLinq2SqlVs1DataContext dt = new OISLinq2SqlVs1DataContext();
        var tr = from r in dt.Users
                 join s in dt.Entities on r.Entity_ID equals s.ID
                 where s.ID == getIntEntity
                 select new
                 {
                     s.Name,
                     r.FirstName,
                     r.LastName,
                     s.Email,
                     //r.Email,
                     r.UserID,
                     r.Pwd,
                     s.Company,
                     s.Description,
                     s.Phone,
                     s.Fax,
                     s.WebSite

                 };

        GridView1.DataSource = tr;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     Height="348px" Width="656px">
</asp:GridView>
```

Now I can see the the value is coming from previous page, but my GridView is not populating anything. What I am doing wrong here? Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your markup for GridView?

Comment: Did that. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `true` which is required to have the data source define what columns appear.

Or you have to manually specify the columns to show.

Comment: THanks Alex, that worked. I want this GridView to be editable. How can I approach that?

Comment: @klm9971, a good example of it could be found on MSDN: [GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Editing the Underlying Data in a GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     Height="348px" Width="656px">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You could remove this answer as I updated your question with it